# Riemann integral interval confusion

Tags: limits, summation, riemann-integration

**The context of this question is in relation to the paragraph of text below from David Bachman's "A Geometric Approach to Differential Forms":**

> [image]

The part that seems contradictory to me is that as $\max\{\Delta x_i\}\rightarrow0$, $n$
 would *necessarily* need to approach infinity. This is because, intuitively, for the size of the largest interval length to approach $0$, there must be an infinite number of $x_i$ (in the limit,... bit handwavey).

**This is what I have done so far; finding a contradiction by assuming that $n$ remain fixed (to try and suggest that $n$ cannot be fixed).**

Define (this is the questionable assumption):
    \begin{equation}\tag{1}
  I_\Delta=\{1,2,\dots,n-1\},\;n\geq 2
 \end{equation}
    Define:
    \begin{equation}\tag{2}
  x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\in [a,b],\;x_i< x_{i+1},\;\forall i\in I_\Delta
 \end{equation}
More specifically, choose $x_1=a,x_n=b$.

Define $\Delta=\{\Delta x_i\}=\{\Delta x_i=x_{i+1} - x_{i}\;|\;i\in I_\Delta\}$

Since all these definitions are used to set up our intuition of splitting an interval $[a,b]$ however we please, we must require that:
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
 \sum_{i\in I_\Delta}\Delta x_i=b-a
\end{equation}
Let $h(C)=C=\max\Delta$. This implies that:
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
 \Delta x_i\leq C,\;\forall i\in I_\Delta
\end{equation}
From (2), $x_i<x_{i+1}\implies \Delta x_i =x_{i+1}-x_i>0\implies 0\leq \Delta x_i$.
Combining (4) with (2), we get that:
\begin{equation}\tag{5}
 0\leq \Delta x_i\leq C,\;\forall i\in I_\Delta
\end{equation}
*For all $\Delta x_i\in \Delta$:*

Let $\lim\limits_{C\rightarrow 0}h(C)=\lim\limits_{C\rightarrow 0}C=0=L$:

Using the squeeze theorem on (5), where $g(C)=0,\;f(C)=\Delta x_i,\;h(C)=C$:
\begin{equation*}
 \lim\limits_{C\rightarrow 0}f(C)=L=0\implies \lim\limits_{C\rightarrow 0}\Delta x_i=0
 \end{equation*}
    \begin{equation}\tag{6}
  \therefore \lim\limits_{\max\Delta\rightarrow 0}\Delta x_i=0,\;\forall \Delta x_i\in \Delta
 \end{equation}
    Taking the limit of (3) we get:
    \begin{align}\tag {3 lim}
  \lim\limits_{\max \Delta \rightarrow 0}\left(\sum_{i\in I_\Delta}\Delta x_i\right)=\lim\limits_{\max \Delta \rightarrow 0}\left(b-a\right)=b-a
 \end{align}
    But we also know that:
    \begin{align*}
  \lim\limits_{\max \Delta \rightarrow 0}\sum_{i\in I_\Delta}\Delta x_i&= \sum_{i\in I_\Delta}\lim\limits_{\max \Delta \rightarrow 0}\Delta x_i=0\neq b-a
 \end{align*}
    which contradicts (3 lim) as $b-a\neq 0$. I suspect that the only way for this to be consistent with requirement (3) is if as $\max\Delta\rightarrow 0,\;n\rightarrow \infty$.

**Is there a flaw in this logic?**

Comment: If $n$ remains fixed how could we get that $\Delta \rightarrow 0$ ??

Comment: **Of course,** if $\max\Delta x_i\to0$, it necessarily follows that $n\to\infty$. However, if $n\to\infty$, it does **not** necessarily follow that $\max\Delta x_i\to0$. And the weaker condition $n\to\infty$ isn't good enough; we need the stronger condition $\max\Delta x_i\to0$ to ensure that the Riemann sums converge to the integral.

Comment: @AmerYR Precisely, I don't think it's possible. I just wanted to clarify that I'm not going crazy, and that $n$ must change (pressumably approaching infinity).

Comment: @bof oh okay, so $n\rightarrow \infty$ is not sufficient, but it is still implied. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the summation above how many $\Delta x_i$ we have? is it changing? or fixed? it could not be fixed. The idea could be clearer if you think about this in the regular approach in analysis i.e. for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists a partition of $[a,b]$, $x_1,\cdots x_n$ such that $max \Delta x_i < \epsilon$. In analysis if we want to prove something approach zero we use for any delta small we can make the value of what we have smaller. Hope this helps