# Ill-defined derivative?

Tags: limits, derivatives, partitions-for-integration

This is a follow-up question to my previous question, [Riemann integral interval confusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3622923), from the same book.

*Below is a snippet of context from the book:*

> [image]

Claim (I should probably be using $\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi_1}{\mathrm{d}a_i}$ here instead of $\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi_1}{\mathrm{d}x}$, but I'm not entirely sure what the correct notation would be):

$\frac{\mathrm{d} \phi_1}{\mathrm{d} x}\Big|_{a_i}=\lim_\limits{\Delta a\rightarrow 0}\left|\frac{\phi_1(a_{i+1})-\phi_1(a_{i})}{\Delta a}\right|$

**These are my thoughts on this matter:**
For $\Delta a$ to even be permitted to approach $0$: $a_{i+1}$, $a_{i}$, or both must be changing as $\Delta a=a_{i+1}-a_{i}$ (I assume).

I think we can assume $a_i$ is fixed/constant, as we want to evaluate the derivative at $a_i$. This implies that $a_{i+1}$ must be changing (fact 1)

However, to evaluate $\frac{\mathrm{d} \phi_1}{\mathrm{d} x}\Big|_{a_{i+1}}$, we need $a_{i+1}$ to be fixed, which is a contradiction with (fact 1).

Hence, $\frac{\mathrm{d} \phi_1}{\mathrm{d} x}\Big|_{a_i}$ is ill-defined.

What is going on here? It seems that this might only make sense if lose the requirement that $a_j,\;i\neq j$ is fixed. But then we only know $\frac{\mathrm{d} \phi_1}{\mathrm{d} x}\Big|_{a_i}$, which is useless when computing the sum over all $a_i,\;\forall i$.

Is this just a non-rigorous leap, which is used to provide intuition as to why there is a "derivative" factor needed to "correct" the integral under parameterisation? Or... is there a flaw in my reasoning, and the derivative is well defined?

Comment: No, you fix $a_i$ when you're computing the derivative at $a_i$.  you fix $a_{i+1}$ when you're computing the derivative there.  Just like always.

Comment: @saulspatz so what are $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$, aren't they described by the partition of the interval you're looking at?

Comment: Maybe I'm jumping to a conclusion here, because the excerpt starts in the middle of the discussion, but when you talk about the mesh of the partition going to $0$, you're necessarily talking about different partitions.  So no, I interpret it to mean that $a_i$ is fixed, and $a_{i+1}$ approaches $a_i$.  That is, it means exactly the same thing as if we had $x$ in place of $a_i$.  The only nit I might pick is that since we usually require that $a_{i+1}>a_i$ this is the right-hand derivative.  But if $\phi_1$ is known to be differentiable, this doesn't matter anyway  ...

Comment: Another way of looking at it is that we know, from the definition of derivative, that when $\Delta a$ is sufficiently small, the difference quotient is arbitrarily close to $\phi_1'(a_i)$, which is all we really need.

Comment: I think I see where you're coming from by fixing them separately, just not really sure how that then applies to the Riemann sum (before we turn it into an integral), I'm just a bit confused about how $a_{i+1}$ and $a_{i}$ are being defined. Thanks though.

Comment: As I said, you can't consider both that the partition is fixed, and the mesh is going to $0$.  Think of them as typical terms.